# $\epsilon$ or empty set union alphabet

Tags: automata, formal-languages

Given an alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$. 
Can you please explain what will be the set in each one of these expressions below:

$$\Sigma \cup \{\epsilon\}\ =\ ?\\ 
    \Sigma \cup \{\emptyset\}\ =\ ?\\
    \Sigma \cup\emptyset\ =\ ?$$

This is really confusing me and I could not find answer for this.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is the *empty set*; thus, for $Σ = \{ 0,1 \}$, $Σ \cup \emptyset = Σ =  \{ 0,1 \}$.

Comment: Changed to 'set' , sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A\cup B$ is the set of things which either are in $A$ or they are in $B$, the three sets are respectively $$\{0,1,\epsilon\}\\ \{0,1,\emptyset\}\\ \{0,1\}$$ Though the significance of the second one as a set of strings is rather questionable, to say the least.

Comment: Awesome , thank you for that. can you please explain the first one? how come empty string "" is a part of alphabet?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is not.